# Clickable progress bar

Tags: javascript

I'm working with angular and developed a clickable progress bar with the help of javascript (it was the best I could).

Is there a way to place the slider inside the progress bar but without interfering with the progress visualization?

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjb7gh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**HTML**

```
<div class="progress aqua" data-width="0%">
    <div class="progress-text">0%</div>
    <div class="progress-bar">
        <div class="progress-text">0%</div>
    </div>
</div>

<input class="slider" id="slider" type="range" name="slider" min="0" max="100" value="0">
```

**COMPONENT**

```
myfuction(){

$(document).ready(function( $ ) {


    $('#slider').on('input',function(e) {
        $('.progress-bar').css('width',(e.target  as HTMLInputElement).value + '%');
    });

    // create an observer instance
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
      mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if (mutation.type == 'attributes' && mutation.attributeName == 'style') {
            var el   = (mutation.target as HTMLInputElement);
            var width  = el.style.width; 
            var $parentEl =$(el).parent('.progress');
            $parentEl.attr('data-width',width);
            $parentEl.find('.progress-text').text(width);
        }
      });
    });

    // configuration of the observer
    var config = {
        attributes: true,
        attributeFilter: ['style'],
        childList: false,
        characterData: false
    };

    $('.progress-bar').each(function(e) {
        // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
        observer.observe(this, config);
    })
});
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ugh1u.png)

The goal is to increase progress with clicks, even if I use the slider to do so, but if it is possible to remove the slider and make the progress bar functional even better.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I know this is already answered but why you use angular if you will manipulate DOM with juqery and mutation observers. Angular is there to abstract that kind of things from you. You will see how it is easier when you use the power of angular binding :

```js
export class AppComponent {

  percentage: string = "0%"; // just expose a porperty

  private updateSliderToggle: boolean = false;

  startUpdateSlider() {
    this.updateSliderToggle = true;
  }

  endUpdateSlider() {
    this.updateSliderToggle = false;
  }

  updateSlider(event) {
    if (this.updateSliderToggle) {
      let percentage: number = Math.floor(
        (event.layerX / (event.target.offsetWidth - 3)) * 100
      );

      if (percentage > 100) {
        percentage = 100;
      } else if (percentage < 0) {
        percentage = 0;
      }
      this.percentage = percentage + "%"; // and manipulate that property
    }
  }
}
```

> In your template make necessary bindings :

```html
<div class="progress aqua" [attr.data-width]="percentage" (mousedown)="startUpdateSlider()"
    (mouseup)="endUpdateSlider()" (mouseleave)="endUpdateSlider()" (mousemove)="updateSlider($event)">
    <div class="progress-text">{{percentage}}</div>
    <div class="progress-bar" [style.width]="percentage">
        <div class="progress-text">{{percentage}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oj2buk)

Comment: Thanks so much for the response from both, but yours fits better for me and had a fantastic performance! Thank you  @pascalpuetz !

Comment: @Eldar Transforming the code to "angular like" code was not the question, as far as I see. Of course this is right, but don't you think a comment would have been a better way instead of copy pasting into a new answer?

Comment: @pascalpuetz comments are not enough to visualize what i mean so i posted as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just don't use the `HTMLInputElement` but listen to mouseevents and calculate the percentage yourself.

In your **component.ts** add the following functions:

```
private updateSliderToggle:boolean = false;

startUpdateSlider() {
  this.updateSliderToggle = true;
}

endUpdateSlider() {
  this.updateSliderToggle = false;
}

updateSlider(event) {
  if (this.updateSliderToggle) {
    let percentage:number = Math.floor(event.layerX / (event.target.offsetWidth - 3) * 100);

    // Might happen, as we set the max to -3 to reach 100% easier.
    if (percentage > 100) {
      percentage = 100;
    } else if (percentage < 0) {
      percentage = 0;
    }

    console.log(event);
    console.log(event.layerX, event.target.offsetWidth);
    $('.progress-bar').css('width', percentage + '%');
  }
}
```

And in your **component.html** change your markup to

```
<div class="progress aqua" data-width="0%" (mousedown)="startUpdateSlider()" (mouseup)="endUpdateSlider()" (mouseleave)="endUpdateSlider()" (mousemove)="updateSlider($event)" >
  <div class="progress-text">0%</div>
  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-text">0%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w4tfz5)