# Progress Bar - Fill Bar with Clicks

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a progress bar that fills in as I drag with the mouse.
Is there any way to fill this bar using clicks inside it?

The bar starts at zero, if clicking goes to 25, if clicking again goes to 50, then 75 and finally in the fourth click reaches 100.

Is there a way to get this?

**My code [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7awjxr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

**html**

```
<div class="progress aqua" [attr.data-width]="progress" (mousedown)="startUpdateSlider(data)"
    (mouseup)="endUpdateSlider(data)" (mouseleave)="endUpdateSlider(data)" (mousemove)="updateSlider($event,data)">
    <div class="progress-text">{{progress}}</div>
    <div class="progress-bar" [style.width]="progress">
        <div class="progress-text">{{progress}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**component**

```
 startUpdateSlider(data) {
    this.updateSliderToggle = true;
  }

  endUpdateSlider(data) {
    this.updateSliderToggle = false;
  }

  updateSlider(event, data) {
    if (this.updateSliderToggle) {

      let percentage: number = Math.floor(
        (event.layerX / (event.target.offsetWidth - 3)) * 100
      );

      if (percentage > 100) {
        percentage = 100;
      } else if (percentage < 0) {
        percentage = 0;
      }
      this.progress = percentage + '%';
    }
  }
```

In my case, the progress bar can be filled with values ​​from 0 to 100.
I want these values ​​to be just 0-25-75-100 and will increase by 25 with each click.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clickable progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59512602/clickable-progress-bar)

Comment: @Eldar Then all the values ​​from 0-100 appear, I want the count to increase by 25 in each click. It's possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove mouseleave and mousemove event handlers. Just leave a click event handler that handles it like this :

```
 updateSlider(event) {
    let percentage: number = Math.floor(
      (event.layerX / (event.target.offsetWidth - 3)) * 100
    );

    const previous = parseInt(this.percentage); // get the previous value
    if (previous > percentage) {
      percentage = previous - 25; // if it is lower decrease 25
    } else {
      percentage = previous + 25; // if it is higher increase 25
    }
    if (percentage > 100) {
      percentage = 100;
    } else if (percentage < 0) {
      percentage = 0;
    }

    console.log(previous);

    this.percentage = percentage + "%";
  }
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oj2buk)

Answer (score 5):

Just add a `(click)` event to your dom.

[Working Stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7dd1vb)

Comment: darn. beat me to it. my effort either way though https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wjtzzv

Comment: @jgritten Yours looks really nice as well - decreasing is not possible with my approach, as that was not part of the question, yours can do that. I'd just try to get rid of the JQuery stuff and go with pure angular :)

Comment: yea, I was building off of Eldar's submission, so props to Eldar. I'm not much of a jQuery fan either but it was working for what i needed at the time. thanks though :D

Comment: Me neither, but that was not the question in that issue. The question was how to realize dragging - which is what I implemented. Eldar only changed a few lines to make it more angular-esque.